# Rails routing not giving wanted result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following route:

```
#routes.rb    
get "(/questions_groups/:group_id)/questions/new" => "questions#new", as: "new_question"
resources :questions
```

Id like calling the `new_question_path(@question_group)` where `@question_group.id = 1` to return the path:

```
/questions_group/1/questions/new
```

Yet it returns:

```
/questions/new?group_id=1
```

When I remove the `resources :questions` I get the correct path but lose all my routes, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: you can try defining the custom route after `resources :questions` as it is being overridden in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call it something different. When you define the resource it comes loaded with a whole bunch of url helpers, in your case one of them is `new_question`, which is the same name as your custom route. If you're trying to replace the route for the new question then tell the resource not to define its own with:

```
resource :questions, except: :new
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
match "/questions_groups/:group_id/questions/new" => "questions#new", as: "new_question"
```

Comment: `resources :questions` will take care of that